# Setting up RealmSwift with Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, realm

I have been trying to install the newest version of Realm (.93) with cocoa pods following the directions on the website:

Install CocoaPods 0.37.1 or later ([sudo] gem install cocoapods).
In your Podfile, add use_frameworks! and pod 'RealmSwift' to your main and test targets.
From the command line, run pod install.
Use the .xcworkspace file generated by CocoaPods to work on your project!

However, when I try to `import RealmSwift` My xcworkspace cannot find the module.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you tried to trigger the first build the project? CocoaPods injects the dependencies implicitly, which causes Xcode troubles to find them at the right place by their module name.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I am new to iOS.  Add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the first build manually.
CocoaPods injects the dependencies implicitly, which causes Xcode troubles to find them at the right place by their module name.